# SQL Server user creation (Windows & SQL Server authentication)

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server administration. I need help from the experts for the below scenarios:

1. How to create Login with Windows Authentication.
2. How to access the database using the same login (Windows Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

If you use T-SQL you can use `CREATE LOGIN` command.

```
CREATE LOGIN [<domainName>\<login_name>] FROM WINDOWS
```

full syntax here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx

To Create Login using SSMS just follow directions from MSDN - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx#SSMSProcedure

To use a given windows authentication you have to login with SSMS or other tool from a computer that you have signed in with specified user, as alternative you can use [`RUN AS` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx) to start SSMS with different credentials other than your own to test it.